# Write a function takes a two-word string and returns True if both words begin with same letter in python

Tags: python

I want to write a function that takes a two-word string and returns True if both words begin with same letter in python.

sample input:
animal_crackers('Levelheaded Llama') --> True
animal_crackers('Crazy Kangaroo') --> False

Comment: Have you done any work to achieve this yet?

Comment: Hi Tyler,

Yes But I am not able to come to any conclusion  I was using string.split(' ') method for the same. But not able to think about the rest of the code. hence put the question instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def animal_crackers(string):
    s1, s2 = string.split(' ')
    print(s1[0].upper() == s2[0].upper())

animal_crackers("levelheaded lama")
```

Comment: Thanks .. Merig..

adding one more approach I tried with double indexing.

def animal_crackers(text):
    
    list_String = text.split()
    return list_String[0][0] == list_String[1][0]

Answer (score 0):

The below code first stores the first character of the string in a variable,then locates the first space in the string,then compares the first character and the first character after the space and returns accordingly.

```
def letter_check(s):

     first_letter= s[0]  #stores the first character of the string in a variable

     for i in range (0,len(s)):
         if(s[i]==" "):         #locates the space in the string
             space_id=i
     if(s[0]==s[space_id+1]):   #compares the first letter with the letter after space
         return[True]
     else:
         return[False]
```

Comment: Thanks but it's lengthy approach..

Answer (score -1):

```
def animal_crackers(words):
    first_word = words.split(" ")[0].lower()
    second_word = words.split(" ")[1].lower()
    if first_word[0] == second_word[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The function above should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's what you're looking for but you can get every letter of a string just by gettings it's index just like in a array. So it should go like this:

```
def check_letter(string):
        # Split function splits string making an array(splits at space at this  example).
        words = string.split()
        # [0][0] means first element and first symbol, [1][0] - 2nd elem, 1st symbol
        if words[0][0] == words[1][0]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```